# Doctrine: Retrieving entities that may not be saved to the database yet

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm parsing a big XML file, with many items. Each item has many categories, which can repeat. Here's a sample XML.

```
<item>
    <category>Category1</category>
    <category>Category2</category>
    <category>Category3</category>
    <category>Category4</category>
    <category>Category5</category>
</item>
<item>
    <category>Category1</category>
    <category>Category2</category>
    <category>Category3</category>
    <category>Category7</category>
    <category>Category9</category>
</item>
```

Using doctrine to handle the many-to-many relationship described above, I have a sample code like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

foreach ($items as $item) {

    [...]

    $categories = ... //Array with category names, parsed from the XML.

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        //This will check if the 'item' entity 
        //already has a category with that name.
        $exists = $entity->getCategories()->exists(function($key, $element) use ($category) {
            return $category == $element->getName();
        });

        if (!$exists) {

            //If there's already one on the database, we'll load it.
            //Otherwise, we'll save a new Category..
            $query = $this->_entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
            $query->select('c')
                  ->from("MyBundle:Category, 'c');
                  ->where("c.name = :name")
                  ->setParameter("name", $category);

            }

            $result = $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

            if ($result != null) {
                $item->addCategory($result);
            } else {
                $categoryEntity = new Category($category);
                $em->persist($categoryEntity);
                $item->addCategory($categoryEntity);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The thing is: I only `flush()` the entitymanager when I complete looping through all items. Therefore, `$query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult()` *always* returns `null`, leading me to create duplicated categories.

In the XML example above, I have the following:

```
| item |
| 1    |
| 2    |

| category.id, category.name |
| 1,           Category1     |
| 2,           Category2     |
| 3,           Category3     |
| 4,           Category4     |
| 5,           Category5     |
| 6,           Category1     |
| 7,           Category2     |
| 8,           Category3     |
| 9,           Category7     |
| 10,          Category9     |

| item | category |
| 1    | 1        |
| 1    | 2        |
| 1    | 3        |
| 1    | 4        |
| 1    | 5        |
| 2    | 6        |
| 2    | 7        |
| 2    | 8        |
| 2    | 9        |
| 2    | 10       |
```

I wanted the following:

```
| item |
| 1    |
| 2    |

| category.id, category.name |
| 1,           Category1     |
| 2,           Category2     |
| 3,           Category3     |
| 4,           Category4     |
| 5,           Category5     |
| 6,           Category7     |
| 7,           Category9     |

| item | category |
| 1    | 1        |
| 1    | 2        |
| 1    | 3        |
| 1    | 4        |
| 1    | 5        |
| 2    | 1        |
| 2    | 2        |
| 2    | 3        |
| 2    | 9        |
| 2    | 10       |
```

Simply adding `$em->flush()` after `$em->persist($categoryEntity)` solves it, but I don't want to flush things just yet (or for that matter, flush only a category). There are a lot of unfinished stuff to do and I don't want to interrupt my transaction. I want to still be able to rollback to the very beginning and exclude all unused categories, if I need to (and, obviously, without running additional queries).

My question is: is there a way to access both the database and doctrine's internal entity mapping to retrieve an entity that might or might not have an ID? Or will I have to create this mapping myself, run a DQL and check on my mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine2 can't do this for you,
but it's pretty easy to store the newly created categories in your loop and check them when you get a MISS from the database.

```
    $_created_categories = array();

    if (!$exists) {
        // If there's already one on the database, we'll load it.
        // Otherwise, we'll save a new Category..

        $query = $this->_entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $query->select('c')
              ->from("MyBundle:Category, 'c');
              ->where("c.name = :name")
              ->setParameter("name", $category);

        $result = $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

        if ($result) {
            $item->addCategory($result);
        elseif ( isset($_created_categories[$category]) ) {
            $item->addCategory($_created_categories[$category]);
        } else {
            $categoryEntity = new Category($category);
            $em->persist($categoryEntity);
            $item->addCategory($categoryEntity);

            $_created_categories[$category] = $categoryEntity;
        }
    }
```

There is no memory overhead to store the new categories entities in the `$_created_categories` array as all objects are manipuled by reference in PHP.

Comment: I was afraid I wouldn't be able to accomplish that with doctrine. The problem is: my class is somewhat different from what I posted above. It's more generic, as it is not supposed to work only with items and categories. It might take a more robust local mapping than a simple array. I'll get started with that right now. Thank you very much for your answer though.